# Why does Marla yank out her tooth?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-care-a-lot

In the movie *I Care A Lot*, Marla nearly drowns. After exiting the water, she pulls out a molar. She then preserves it and has a dentist put it back. Maybe I missed something, but why would she do this?

Comment: Did she yank it out or just take it out because it was loose? After all, she's just been in a crash and that would likely cause damage to one's teeth

Comment: I thought about that.  If it were merely loose, I would leave it in place since it still has some blood flow, she is clearly knowledgeable on how to care for lost teeth.  If it were knocked clean out I imagine she would have just spit it out, not reaching in deep to grab it.

Comment: You might but clearly the scene has to play out this way to show that she is hurt.